# How to set the SliverAppBar's Title style from the MaterialApp's theme parameter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar, flutter-theme, flutter-sliverappbar

If I would like to set the style of a regular appbar title from the MaterialApp theme parameter, I would do the following:

```
 ThemeData(appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
  textTheme: TextTheme(
    headline6: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      fontSize: 37,
    ),
  ),
),
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same thing for a SliverAppBar. I am aware that you can simply set the style of the Text widget assigned to the title parameter within the SliverAppBar widget, but I'm trying to see if I can achieve the same result from the app's custom theme instead.

Comment: One way (but probably not _the_ way to do this, would be to set the style in the `SliverAppBar` for each property to the values for the regular AppBar in your app-wide `ThemeData`.

Comment: @fravolt Thanks for the creative idea. I'll give it a go :)